# Refreshing GUI without using repaint(), revalidate()

Tags: java, user-interface, refresh

I have a frame with several panels. Whenever I press/release/click the center panel, a JLabel shows the amount of times and the coordinate where I have performed such an action. The problem is that the window doesn't refresh, so all these values on JLabel stay at 0. Usually with paintComponents I would use `repaint()`, but I'm not using this method.

Here is the piece of code where I am supposed to 'repaint':

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    pressCounter++;
    x = e.getX();
    y = e.getY();
    buildIt(); //this works, but doesn't do what i want it to do
}
```

Calling `buildIt()` actually works, but it would open a new window after every action, instead of refreshing the original window. I've also tried `revalidate()` and `removeAll()` here, but they don't seem to do anything at all.

**So how do I refresh the window?**

Here is the complete code for reference:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class MouseMonitor extends JPanel implements MouseListener {
    JFrame frame;
    JPanel topPanel, centerPanel, bottomPanel;
    JLabel pressLabel, releaseLabel, clickLabel, xLabel, yLabel;

    int pressCounter = 0;
    int releaseCounter = 0;
    int clickCounter = 0;

    int x, y;

    void buildIt() {
        frame = new JFrame("Mouse Monitor");
        topPanel = new JPanel();
        centerPanel = new JPanel();
        bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        pressLabel = new JLabel("pressed: " + pressCounter);
        releaseLabel = new JLabel("released: " + releaseCounter);
        clickLabel = new JLabel("clicked: " + clickCounter);
        xLabel = new JLabel("x-coordinate: " + x);
        yLabel = new JLabel("y-coordinate: " + y);

        frame.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        topPanel.add(pressLabel);
        topPanel.add(releaseLabel);
        topPanel.add(clickLabel);
        bottomPanel.add(xLabel);
        bottomPanel.add(yLabel);
        pressLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.WHITE));
        releaseLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.WHITE));
        clickLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.WHITE));
        xLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.WHITE));
        yLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.WHITE));

        Color color = new Color(193, 236, 255);
        centerPanel.setBackground(color);
        centerPanel.addMouseListener(this);

        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        pressCounter++;
        x = e.getX();
        y = e.getY();
        buildIt();
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        releaseCounter++;
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        clickCounter++;
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) { }
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) { }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MouseMonitor().buildIt();
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of building a whole new frame, just change the contents of the  `xLabel` and `yLabel`.

Comment: Didn't I do this by writing `x = e.getX();` and `y = e.getY();` ?

Comment: No. That sets the value of `x` and `y`. There is no code except in the **creation** of your windows that connects between `x` and `y` and the labels. You need to explicitly set the labels to a new value each time you want them to change, using `xLabel.setText(...)`, `yLabel.setText(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call the `built()` method to refresh the frame or panel. For the purpose of what you want, you just have to change the text on the label. So for instance, considering `mousePressed(MouseEvent e)` method, take out the `buildIt()` method:

```
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        pressCounter++;
        pressLabel.setText("pressed: " + pressCounter);

    }
```

Do this for each of the methods and you are good to go. Maintain code in the `main` method.